# Crontab error Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cron

I have an issue when i try to modify or see my crontab commands, its only for this commands, the wear thing its the proccess are running OK

when I execute

```
root@subuntu-1604:~# crontab -l
```

or

```
root@subuntu-1604:~# crontab -e
```

I get the follow

```
/usr/local/bin/crontab: line 11: 17: command not found

/usr/local/bin/crontab: line 12: 25: command not found

/usr/local/bin/crontab: line 13: 47: command not found

/usr/local/bin/crontab: line 14: 52: command not found
```

Yesterday that was working ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/` isn't the normal location for the `crontab` binary - it looks like you have a text file there that is overriding the system's `crontab`

Comment: i have binary OK on /usr/bin, the file on /usr/local/bin contents the follow text

Comment: as you say, i delete that file, it was copied from an olded server, thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

As steeldriver says, that file was wrong, that file corresponds to and older version of ubuntu, i delete that file and back to normal, thans a lot.